# Pouring wine into a pagum/used cup in order to reuse the wine inside

Tags: halacha, shabbat, shiurim-measurements, grapes-wine, kiddush

I heard that after drinking from the kiddish cup, in order to reuse the wine left over which is *pagum*, we pour some wine into the cup from the bottle it before pouring the wine in the cup back into the bottle. This *un-pagums* (makes the wine re-usable) the wine for usage for *Kiddush* in the future. Does it matter if there is more wine in the cup than in the bottle?  Or would it still work if there is very little wine in the bottle, even less than in the cup.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya! Please take a moment to look over our [tour], as this site might be different from other sites you're used to. For those who aren't familiar with the terminology, could you please [edit] your post to explain what "pagum" means and how this would theoretically work to "unpagum" it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Bach Orach Chaim 182,3](https://www.sefaria.org/Bach%2C_Orach_Chaim.182.3.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) brings how to fulfil all opinions (thanks @Magiker72 for reference) to un pagum a cup of used Kiddush wine as the questioner assumed:

> כדי לצאת ידי חובתו בפלוגתא דרבוואתא יש לשפוך תחלה מעט מן הקנקן לתוך כוס הפגום שבזה נתקן הפגימה למקצת רבוותא דלא כמהר"ם דקמא קמא בטיל ונעשה הכל פגום ואח"כ מערה הכל כל מה שבכוס לתוך הקנקן לא בשפיכה אחת אלא במעט מעט עד שיערה כולו דהשתא קמא קמא בטיל בקנקן וניתקן הכל לדעת מהר"ם.....**כתב מהר"ם מ"ץ דכוס פגום אין יכולין למלאותו ולתקנו אלא מכוס שיש בו רביעית**
>
> In order to fulfil ones obligation according to all opinions, one must pour a little wine from the pitcher into the *Pagum* (drunk from) cup [which will not satisfy the Maharam Rottenberg's opinion as all the new wine poured in gets nullified by the Pagum wine in the used cup, but this will satisfy the Mahari Speyer who says earlier to add a little wine to "renew" the old wine in the cup]. Afterwords, one should pour the entire cup back into the pitcher drop by drop (i.e not a constant stream) so that each drop of Pagum wine is nullified by the good wine in the pitcher [so that one fulfils his obligation of Kiddush even according to the Maharam]... **The Maharam Metz writes that one can only fix a Pagum cup of wine with another untouched cup/pitcher containing a *Reviis*(86/150cc) of wine** (according to the Maharam who requires pouring the cup back into the pitcher).

Answer (score 0):

The Shulchan Aruch in [Orach Chaim 182:6](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.182.6?lang=bi&with=Commentary&lang2=he) says that once you have poured *a little* wine into the cup, it is no longer Pagum. Even a bit of water would do the trick.

> יכולין לתקן כוס פגום ע"י שיוסיפו מעט יין ואפי' ע"י שיוסיפו עליו מים מיתקן:‏

Once the cup is no longer Pagum, then why would it make the wine in the bottle Pagum?

(This seems to be the way the Shulchan Aruch paskens, it's possible that others disagree.)